# Strange behaviour in MS Access: Delete Table with mouse != Delete Table with VBA

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I need some help with VBA in MS Access!
Following setup: There is a table "tblTablesToLink":

| ID | FileName | TableName | ImportSpecification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SL100.txt | raw_ReadData | SL2100-Import |
| 2 | objects.txt | raw_Coordinates | Coordinate-Import |

I have set up an AutoExec in Access that contains a lot of code.
After starting Access, I want:

1. Get the current Project Path for the access database
2. Load some txt files as linked tables into access
3. Convert the linked tables to local tables for further calculations

There will be more - just ignore it for now.

```
Public Function StartUp()
    Dim strPathToFiles As String
    Dim myDB As DAO.Database
    Dim rstFilesToLink As DAO.Recordset

    strPathToFiles = CurrentProject.Path & "\RawData\"
    Set myDB = CurrentDb

    ' Link Data to Access Database ====================
    Set rstFilesToLink = myDB.OpenRecordset("tblTablesToLink", dbReadOnly)
    
    With rstFilesToLink
        Do While Not .EOF
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable = acDefault, ![TableName]
            DoCmd.TransferText _
            TransferType:=acLinkDelim, _
            SpecificationName:=![ImportSpecification], _
            TableName:=![TableName], _
            FileName:=strPathToFiles & ![FileName], _
            HasFieldNames:=False
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    rstFilesToLink.Close
    Set rstFilesToLink = Nothing
    ' =================================================

    ' Convert linked data into local tables ===========
    DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "raw_ReadData", True
    RunCommand acCmdConvertLinkedTableToLocal
    DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "raw_Coordinates", True
    RunCommand acCmdConvertLinkedTableToLocal
    ' =================================================
End Function
```

So my code is running w/o errors exactly one time.
Access is linking the two txt files and converts them into local tables.
Re-running this function will just link the txt files w/o converting.
I've also added `DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable = acDefault, raw_ReadData` and `DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable = acDefault, raw_Coordinates` at the beginning of my function just to be sure.

Nothing changes.

I have to re-run the code a second time to convert the tables again. So I need two runs of the same code...

It will work as expected multiple times if I'm deleting both tables by hand via right mouse click in the Access window and re-running the code. WTF?! So "DeleteObject" isn't the same as "Delete"?
What am I doing wrong? Or is there another simple way to load txt data in a local table?

Comment: Why delete tables? Does data structure change? If not, could just delete records and import to existing tables. I don't understand `acTable = acDefault`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACCESS VBA code to delete a table if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833709/access-vba-code-to-delete-a-table-if-it-exists)

Comment: Why use linked tables? Why not import directly to local tables?

Comment: Because the txt files can contain uo to several billions of rows. I need a fast way to import a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the table each time, import the text and archive the text file. This way you aren't processing a growing text file, you are only adding new data.

```
'@Description("ISO Compliant file timestamp")
Public Function ISOTimeStamp(Optional ByVal zulu As Boolean) As String
Attribute ISOTimeStamp.VB_Description = "ISO Compliant file timestamp"
    If zulu Then
        ISOTimeStamp = Format$(ConvertUTC(Now), "yyyy-MM-ddThhmmssZ")
    Else
        ISOTimeStamp = Format$(Now, "yyyy-MM-ddThhmmss")
    End If
End Function



Public Function StartUp()
    Dim strPathToFiles As String
    Dim myDB As DAO.Database
    Dim rstFilesToLink As DAO.Recordset

    strPathToFiles = CurrentProject.Path & "\RawData\"
    Set myDB = CurrentDb

    ' Link Data to Access Database ====================
    Set rstFilesToLink = myDB.OpenRecordset("tblTablesToLink", dbReadOnly)
    
    With rstFilesToLink
        Do While Not .EOF
            Dim originalFile As String
            originalFile = strPathToFiles & ![FileName]

            ' Clear the old data out of the table
            Docmd.RunSQL “DELETE * FROM " & ![TableName] & ";”

            ' Load fresh data from the text file
            DoCmd.TransferText _
            TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
            SpecificationName:=![ImportSpecification], _
            TableName:=![TableName], _
            FileName:=originalFile, _
            HasFieldNames:=False

            Dim archiveFile As String
            archiveFile = CurrentProject.Path & "\ImportedData\" & ![FileName] & ISOTimeStamp

            ' Move the file to archive
            Name originalFile As archiveFile

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    rstFilesToLink.Close
    Set rstFilesToLink = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: That is a nice solution that I will try the next days. But i have to remove the tables because the SL2100.txt is a logfile from a hardware module that contains X and Y coordinates for a specific process. I need the data for further calculations. After that, a report is printed and the data can be dropped. A new SL2100.txt is added later and at this point, the tables must be empty (better restarting at ID 1).

Comment: Whenever you want to clear out the data you can use `Docmd.RunSQL “DELETE * FROM NameOfTable;”` . However, don't you want to keep the data for historical purposes? The text file archive has the raw data but do you ever need to go back to it later?

Comment: Normally, I would use a date field to track the dataset and then you can select by date range to get the dataset you need for a given report. I would only want to clear out the data if it physically didn't fit in an AccessDB. Even then, that's a case to move to an SQL backend. SQL Express gives you 10GB for free.